# Display values in a div using each

Tags: jquery, text, each

I got a `li` with several `input checkboxes`:

```
<form id="select">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Material">Material</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="Stuff">Stuff</li>
</form>

<div class="show"></div>
```

I'd like to print these values in a div using jQuery.

```
$("#select li input").each(function() {
  var theTag   = $(this).attr("name");
  var theValue = $(this).attr("value");

  $(".show").text(theValue + " " + theTag);
});
```

How display it?

Thank you

Comment: In your code change $(".show").text("") to $(".show").append("") will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/o0scybLo/

```js
$('#select li').each(function(){
   $('.show').append($(this).find('input').attr('name') + ": " + $(this).find('input').attr('value') + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="select">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Material">Material</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="Stuff">Stuff</li>
</form>

<div class="show"></div>
```

Used `append` instead of `html` or `text` for appending the text.

Answer (score 1):

1. use map to create an array
2. use `.html()` to render in div
3. use `.join()` to join each array element with a

```js
var arr=$("#select li input").map(function() {
  var theTag   = $(this).attr("name");
  var theValue = $(this).attr("value");

  return theValue + " " + theTag;
}).get();

$(".show").html(arr.join('</br>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="select">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="material" value="Material">Material</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="stuff" value="Stuff">Stuff</li>
  </ul>
</form>

<div class="show"></div>
```